# NumberFormat not giving correct Number

Tags: java

i have this code:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;


class EntryPoint {
    static Locale czech = null;

    static Locale getCzechLocale(){
        if (czech == null){
           czech = new Locale("cs","CZ");
        }
        return czech;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(getCzechLocale());
        System.out.println(nf.format(12000.5));
        NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getCzechLocale());
        try {
            String input = sn.nextLine();
            System.out.println(input);
            Number n = nf.parse(input);
            System.out.println(n.floatValue());
        }catch(ParseException javaTextParseException){
           System.err.println("Unable to parse input String");
        }
   }

}
```

I want to archive this thing: if I enter number "12 000,5" (as is program displaying) program parse and this String and will display number "12000.5".
What i have wrong ?
Now if I enter "12 000,5" without " sign program display float number "12.0" not "12000.5"

**Solved**
NumberFormat.Parse(String) will end on first space char, so if I make trim() and Replace(" ","") then result is OK.

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: I'm on system with "en_US" locale, so i need enter text in "cs_CZ" format and display in "en_US"

Comment: @Henry because if i Enter "12 000,5" i have result "12.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumberFormat doesn't stop on first space. It's just that the grouping separator used by the NumberFormat you're using is a non-breaking space, and not a regular space.

If you copy and paste the output from your program to pass it as input, it will happily parse it back to 12000.5, because the output uses a non-breaking space.

If you want it to use a regular space character, use

```
DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("cs", "CZ"));
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = nf.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
decimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
nf.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code, it worked for me:

```
        Locale czech = new Locale("cs", "CZ");
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(czech);
        String input = sn.nextLine();
        System.out.println(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(input)));
        sn.close();
```

Comment: not working for me: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /Users/jvalek/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/out/artifacts/HelloWorld_jar/HelloWorld.jar
12 000,5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12 000,5"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:22)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You need not enter 12 000,5 yourself, you should just enter 12000.5 and the code above will do the rest.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a fixed format like `## ###,#` consider using a fixed format parser like DecimalFormat:

```
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("### ###.##");
Number n=nf.parse("123 456,78");
```